# Loop around web service call fails 10% of the time, get error: Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a proxy service that makes a call to a 3rd party web service. I'm calling the method in my proxy service 5000 times in a loop. I'm getting this error on about 100 of the calls in the middle of the loop (about 4000 work successfully, then about 100 errors, then it finishes the remaining 900 successfully).

This is the error that is getting thrown server-side:

> System.InvalidOperationException Message Failed to handle request.
>   Method
>
> > System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type
>
> > type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>
> > context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>
> > context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
>
> at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>
> > Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Additional Information
>
> > +System.InvalidOperationException:
> >     +System.Web.HttpException:
> >
> > ```
> >  Message: Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent. 
> >
> >  Source: System.Web 
> >
> >  Method: System.Web.HttpResponse.ClearHeaders
> > ```

The error that I see client-side is:

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad
>   Request.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)

The googling that I've found so far just relates to file transfers on servers. Can anyone point me in a different direction?

Edit: I just checked the my server that's hosting the proxy service and noticed this error in the EventViewer/EventLog:

> - 
> - 0    2    0
>     0x80000000000000    
>     569114
>     Application
>     labdevapp21.dot.labidot.lan
> - HTTP/ASMX Message Receive Failure: System.InvalidOperationException: The value may not be accessed in
>     message stage 0. at
>     System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.EnsureStage(SoapMessageStage
>     stage) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.get_ContentType()
>     at
>     Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.CheckMtomContentType(SoapServerMessage
>     message) at
>     Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.CreateRequestSoapEnvelope(SoapServerMessage
>     message) at
>     Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.GetRequestEnvelopeFromMessage(SoapServerMessage
>     message)